# Unexpected behavior at the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

MS Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

I have wrote some class. Then I have wrote unit tests for it. Please, look at the my first screen:

[image]

If I run unit test via "1" button, then  a code works as I have expect, but if I run unit test via "2" button, then I have unexpected behavior. Please, look at the my second screen:

[image]

When the condition

```
if (null == acadRegistryKey)
```

is true, I press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key and go to row number 175. I press <kbd>F10</kbd> key again, and... I go to row number 177. Why it happens??? After row number 175 I must have return from method, because exception must occur.

Best Regards, 
Andrey

Comment: Is he switching threads during stepping or is this happening inside the same thread?

Comment: @Uwe Keim At my class code, and at my unit test code, I not use the threads.